# How can I pass properties placeholder to annotations from YAML config file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I want to pass my config properties from YAML file to annotations value like this: `@SendTo(value = "${config.ws.topic}")`, but get an error

> Could not resolve placeholder config.ws.topic etc ..

My Code:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.register")
@SendTo("${config.websocket.topic}")
public Message addUser(@Payload Message message,
                       SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", message.getSender());
    return message;

}
```

Prop-es file:

```
server:
  address: 127.0.0.1
  port: 8080

config:
  websocket:
    endpoint: /ns/ws/endpoint
    appPrefix: /ns/ws
    topic: /ns/ws/ns-topic
```

Props config class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "config.websocket")
public class WebSocketConfigurationProperties {
  private String endpoint;
  private String appPrefix;
  private String topic;

public String getEndpoint() {
    return endpoint;
}

public void setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
}

public String getAppPrefix() {
    return appPrefix;
}

public void setAppPrefix(String appPrefix) {
    this.appPrefix = appPrefix;
}

public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public void setTopic(String topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
} 
}
```

Could you please advise me on how to pass the config properties to annotations `@SendTo`?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to map values from application.yml to your props cofig class?

Comment: @Coder I am just want to set value from application.yml to my controller class, namly to annotation. I want to map values from application yaml (namly config.websocket.topic) to annotation SendTo in my controller class. I want to do this because when I change the names of the topic in the properties configuration file, it also changed in the controller class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to map values from application.yml to your configuration class you can simply make use of `@Value` for this purpose.

In your controller simply create variables which will hold the information from `application.yml` like as specified below

```
@Value("${config.ws.topic}")
String topic;
```

and your controller will look as below

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.register")
@SendTo(topic)
public Message addUser(@Payload Message message,
                       SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", message.getSender());
    return message;

}
```

Edit 1: Due to the following error **Attribute value must be constant**, there is a work around to solve the issue.

```
@Value("${config.ws.topic}")
String topic;

public static final String TOPIC_VALUE = "" + topic;
```

and your controller will look as below

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.register")
@SendTo(TOPIC_VALUE)
public Message addUser(@Payload Message message,
                       SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", message.getSender());
    return message;
```

Comment: I tried to do it but got compile error "Attribute value must be constant"

Comment: thanks you very much! But, i thinks this (public static final String TOPIC_VALUE = "" + topic;) is  bad practise becaus i got compile error : Non static field cannot be referenced etc. I hope finde 
more professional way.

Comment: It's not a good practice for sure. I just included it as a work around, but I am welcome for suggestions. Even I prefer to learn :)